# Python : DataFrame.to_excel should write the table vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write 2 Sheets in a new Excel file

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(outputDetailsFile) as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FA',index = False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TA', index = False)
```

The above code is working fine.
There is only 1 row in that in "df1"
Therefore, I need the First Sheet "FA" to be written Vertically instead of Horizontally for better readability

At present it is writing like this :
[image]

It should Write like this :

[image]

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try transposing the index and columns using the `T` accessor:

`df1.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FA',index = False)`